# How to modify the font of the left navigation bar of my MySQL

Tags: mysql, workbench

The font on the left navigation bar of my MySQL workbench is too small for me to see clearly. Like the picture below, how to modify the font to make it look better
[image]

Comment: I don't believe that ypou can do it, besides inceereasind the system to 125 or 150 per cent, it seems it is harcoded.

Comment: Do you mean this is caused by system scaling?And we can't modify the font size of the navigation bar.

Comment: Yes, i mean that, if you increase the font size if the system it also increases, as almost all programs